# Prevent page from jumping to the top onclick JS

Tags: javascript

I have this inline JS call to a function inside an anchor tag and when click it fires the JS function however I don't want the page to jump to the top when I click it.

```
<a href="#" title="link" onclick="javascript:runMe()">Click Here</a>
```

And I have this inside the function:

```
function runMe() {
// do something
return false;
}
```

I thought the return false would be the correct way to prevent it to jump to the top but it doesn't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not returning the return of the function. :P Basically you are only returning false to the runMe function call but not the element's onclick function call.

do

```
<a href="#" title="link" onclick="runMe(); return false;">Click Here</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" title="link" onclick="return runMe();">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: The `javascript:` part isn't needed either, since it's in `onclick`.

Comment: doh! forgot to mention that... it's late XD have mercy on me.

Comment: Just to mention the second option doesn't work...it still jumps..the first works though...thanks again!

Comment: `return !1` is slighter shorter alternative... not that we going for verbose or short code

Comment: The # in the href isn't needed either.

Comment: @JaydenLawson eh... I tend to keep it in there just because it's a nice fallback for if javascript is not working (disabled or elsewhere errored out).  Otherwise with an empty string, it refreshes the current page (at least in chrome).